# Is there's an way to trigger an function based on firestore document read?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to trigger a cloud function on a firestore specific document read according to the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) there's no such "events".

Can someone guide me please ?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Triggering a cloud function on a document read is not possible. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to do some checks when the document got read (like changing some fields based on timestamp, etc.)

Comment: That document can be read only by a single user?

Comment: nope, multiple users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to trigger a Cloud Function upon a read from the database.

The typical reason for requesting this feature is that you want to transform the data that the user is reading. There are two common approaches for this:

1. Implement a Cloud Functions that reads the data, typically as a HTTPS triggered function or a Callable Function. This Cloud Function then connects to the database, reads the base data, transforms the data to what you want it to be, and returns that to the user.
2. Implement the transformation whenever the data is being written/updated. This is the more idiomatic NoSQL approach, where you do extra work on write operations, so that read operations become simpler and more scalable.